# StripePaymentSheet couldn't add two cards in one session

Tags: swift

Each time I try to add two cards in one session, I receive an error in StripePaymentSheet
"You can not update this SetupIndent because it has already succeeded"

If I get new customerEphemeralKey and intentForCustomer, it continues adding cards. But I need to detect that card was added and close the popup.

Do you have any delegate to detect it?

This is how I use it

```
@IBAction func onPayments() {
        
        SVProgressHUD.show()
        Task(priority: .background) {
            do {
                let customerAdapter = try await NetworkService.getCustomerAdapter()
                var configuration = CustomerSheet.Configuration()

                configuration.headerTextForSelectionScreen = "Manage your payment method"

                let customerSheet = CustomerSheet(configuration: configuration, customer: customerAdapter)
                
                
                await SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
                customerSheet.present(from: self) { result in
                        print(result)
                }
            } catch {
                Alert.showNativeError(customMessage: error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0oThO.png)

Maybe you have any bette idea or I made a mistake in implementation